# How do I find the kernel config for my ROM?

Tags: cyanogenmod, kernel, external-keyboard, samsung-galaxy-ace-2

I'm very happy with CM11 ported to my phone(Samsung Galaxy Ace 2). One day I bought Bluetooth keyboard.

When I tried to connect it, it paired and... wat? No connection!? I thought that this ROM has some bug, so i looked at logcat. I found that there's no uhid driver and I think that developers didn't compile kernel with "CONFIG_UHID=y".

I'm gonna compile new kernel.

First I need to check it, but there's no /proc/config.gz. How can I check(and compile) that without it?

ROM homepage: http://novafusion.pl/

EDIT: Seems like that other CM/AKOP ROM's for my device don't have uhid support(or kernel source is crap?). Keyboard works fine with Stock ROM

Comment: Hello did you got UHID support or you are waiting to 3.6 kernel? I am facing the same problem :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the kernel wasn't compiled with /proc/config.gz support turned on, then the only sure way is to look at the source tree that was used to compile the kernel you're running. Copy the config.h file into your own source tree (or just use the original source tree) and run `make menuconfig` to set any new options you want.

Comment: okay, I did so, and got working kernel. But still, UHID isn't in `make menuconfig` or in ".config". No e-mail answer from developers too. In fact kernel version is **3.0.101**. I need to use custom rom, because stock is so slow and I hate lagging phones.

Comment: Got it! CM uses uhid, but stock rom does use uinput. That's why I can't connect. uhid support starts at kernel 3.6